# Radeon VII only draws 150W at 100% load

Tags: graphics-card, performance, power-supply, amd-radeon

I've noticed in HW monitor my radeon VII only draws in around 150W of power when doing a 3D render or benchmark…

[image: Here's the image]

Does anyone know why exactly this is happening? I've got an 8 pin to 8+6 pin cable in my corsair 850W power supply.
I've also noticed instability when rendering anything... Like the screen going black, audio still playing for a minute or 2 and then nothing; while the fans are going full force. Only a system restart fixes this.

Comment: How much power were you expecting the card to draw?

Comment: The rating for the radeon VII is 300W, and draws this much during benchmarks online.

Comment: Check what that rail can actually push, from the PSU datasheet or manual.

Comment: @Julien - Only the reference cards power rating is 300 W.  What frequency is your card running at when it's under full load?  Your screenshot does not indicate that information.  I don't trust the 1850 Mhz, since the boost frequency for the reference card, is only 1750 Mhz.  **I don't believe that to be the frequency of the core**  The reported frequency of your CPU does not appear to be correct is the reason I am suspect.

Comment: The screenshot only shows data for the GPU, i have an Asrock version which boosts somewhat further.